# Variable in split not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a unique domain name from commentators on my blog. But I am constrained by the variable that appears.

Here I made two variables like this:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="comment_name">
        <a href="http://tes.wordpress.com">Sofyan</a>
        <div id="nameHost"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="comment_name">
        <a href="http://tes.blogspot.com">Selfie</a>
        <div id="nameHost"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var nameSite=[
        'wordpress',
        'blogspot'
    ];

    $(".comment_name a").attr('id', function(){
        return $(this).attr('href').split(".")[1];
    });


    for(var vol = 0; vol < nameSite.length; vol = vol+1){
        $("a[id='"+nameSite[vol]+"']").each(function(){
            $(this).closest(".container").find("#nameHost")
                .replaceWith("<div id='nameHost'>Host by: "+nameSite+" ..</div>");
        })
    }
</script>
```

However, that appears precisely both. I hope there is the best solution from this site. Thank you

Comment: what is your current issue. can't make it from your question

Comment: I might be wrong, but could it be that `a[id=...]` is not a valid jQuery selector? Why aren't you using `"a#"+nameSite[vol]`?

Comment: note: `$("a[id='"+nameSite[vol]+"']").each` - you'd only ever expect this to return 0 or 1 element, so, you'd never need `.each` - that implies you could get 2 or more! - also, `$("a[id='"+nameSite[vol]+"']")` is identical to `$("#"+nameSite[vol])`

Comment: your html also contains multiple elements with the same **id** - not only is this invalid HTML, it also may cause unexpected results in javascript

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister `a[id=...]`, isn't invalid jQuery selector. But `"a#"+nameSite[vol]` preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var vol = 0; vol < nameSite.length; vol = vol+1){
    $("a[id='"+nameSite[vol]+"']").each(function(){
        $(this).closest(".container").find("#nameHost")
            .replaceWith("<div id='nameHost'>Host by: "+

                nameSite[vol] // I think this is your problem `vol`

            +" ..</div>");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code tidied up and working

major changes:

- changed id="nameHost" to class="nameHost" - because id's in HTML **MUST** be unique
- in nameSite loop only look for one element with id="???" - for the same reason as above

```js
var nameSite=[
        'wordpress',
        'blogspot'
    ];

    $(".comment_name a").attr('id', function(){
        return $(this).attr('href').split(".")[1];
    });


    $.each(nameSite, function(index, value) {
        $('#' + value)
            .closest(".container")
            .find(".nameHost")
            .replaceWith("<div id='nameHost'>Host by: "+value+" ..</div>");
    });
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="comment_name">
        <a href="http://tes.wordpress.com">Sofyan</a>
        <div class="nameHost"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="comment_name">
        <a href="http://tes.blogspot.com">Selfie</a>
        <div class="nameHost"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

both values are in the variable `nameSite`

```
.replaceWith("<div id='nameHost'>Host by: " + nameSite + " ..</div>");
```

so you have to index the one you want

```
.replaceWith("<div id='nameHost'>Host by: " + nameSite[vol] + " ..</div>");
```

http://codepen.io/activedecay/pen/wMdjeV