# Replacing the contents of the DIV If the URL By Name Not Included

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have the arrangement of HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="http://name-domain.com">User Without</a>
<div id="comment">
This comment.. //This will be replaced automatically
</div>

<a href="https://www.blogger.com/profile/123456789">Name User</a>
<div id="comment">
This comment..
</div>
</div>
```

I only allow users to comment using blogger account and Anonymous. If there are users commented using a URL other than the one I want, then the comment content will be replaced automatically with javascript or jquery.

For example:

```
$("#comment").html("You may only use the commenting blogger account and Anonymous")
```

or

```
document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML="You may only use the commenting blogger account and Anonymous";
```

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing. But I really want the code to be installed on my blog. Please help if anyone can. Thank you..

Comment: yes please....clear your question first..its confusing.

Comment: you have two elements with the same id (comment) ... invalid HTML that will cause you all sorts of issues

Comment: @Just code - Some time ago I have found the answer to that question of them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688914/variable-in-split-not-work)

However, now I have a problem to develop

Comment: But, can you describe your problem? its difficult to assume what you are expecting